# cakePHP script that will all a function

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hie..I want help on a cakePHP script that will refresh or call a function in the controller after specified time interval.

```
public function testwebservices(){
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");  
    $options = array( 
    'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,           
    'exceptions'=>true,                 
    'trace'=>1,                     
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE       
);
$wsdl = "http://example.com/service.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
$lastrec = rec5000;         
$rec = $client->GetReceipt(array('txnRef'=>$lastrec));
$result = $rec->GetReceiptRez;
```

i want to call the above function to so that it will be automatically executed after a specified time.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're best bet might be to just schedule a cron-job. It would make more sense then expecting your web-framework to schedule anything for you. And of course, whatever script you call in your cron-job will need to be responsible for loading any necessary files that you need (from cakePHP).

Comment: Ok..Thanx John let me try that out.I thought maybe there could be some function like the setTimeout() in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best bet is to go with a cron-task (if you're on a Unix/Linux machine). The cron task could be written in a couple of ways.

**First:**  You could call your script directly with the PHP interpreter and the script you'd run in your cron may look like

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/php /full/path/to/script.php
```

However, you'll need to take notice that you will not get the benefits of your framework. That means that any framework utilities that you are using, you will have to load yourself in your `script.php` file. If this is too much (loading all the required utils), then you can do it another way.

**Second:** You can create an endpoint, such as `/test/web-service` and you can setup a cron to make a web-request to that script which will check that the web service is running correctly. In that case you would have a simply cURL request that might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://mysite.com/test/web-service
```

The benefit of this approach is that you could really put this on any machine (if you make the URL public) and you get the benefit of having your framework (cakePHP in this case) being loaded and all of the utils being available to you.